# Any issues if MYSQL max_connections is set to a higher value than the applications needed

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have an application that is pointed to MySQL 5.7 and it requires more than the default MySQL max_connections(151) while it is started. But, it will gradually reduce (to around 20 connections) after several minutes of server startup. So, in order to start the server, I have configured the max_connections to 500 in etc/my.cnf file.

My questions is, will there be any resource utilization, performance or any other issue from MySQL Server side if I keep the same max connections throughout the server running time, although that much of connections will not be used later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_connections` is a global variable that can have a *minimum* value of 1 and a *maximum* value of 100000. However, It has always been commonly known that settings max_connections to an insanely high value is not too good for performance. Generations of system administrators have followed this rule.

**500 is a not a big value what so ever.** When it comes to performance `max_connections` value is always bounded to server specs and if it is not in use or idles no performance issue will occur. Therefore there will be less probability to happen a performance issue in this case if you have good specs(more than 8GB ram - this depends on your processing load).